# Circular Hough transform using edge gradients and orientations

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, detection, hough-transform

I'm currently busy with implementing two circular Hough transforms. The last one is based on an idea which is described in a paper for iris segmentation (http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/naditya/Aditya_Nigam_icic2012P_C.pdf). 
I've tried to implement every step but this kind of circular detection doesn't give any positive and accurate results. Also when running this algorithm on an image, containing a simple circle without noise, the maximum value which appears in the accumulator matrix is mostly around 3 (which means that only 3 edge points where found, voting for this center point...). Based on my outcomes, I guess this has something to do with a mistake within my code? Or maybe I forgot to implement a crucial step?

```
% create binairy edge image
edgeImage = double(edge(image,'sobel'));

% create sobel masks
horizontalMaskSobel = fspecial('sobel');
verticalMaskSobel = fspecial('sobel')';

% calculate gradients
gradientX = imfilter(edgeImage,horizontalMaskSobel);
gradientY = imfilter(edgeImage,verticalMaskSobel);

% calculate the orientation for each edge within the image
orientationImage = atan2(gradientY,gradientX);

% create accumulator space
for y in searchwindow % height
    for x in searchwindow % width
        for r in radii;
            if edgeImage(y,x) > 0 % bright enough?
                cy1 = y + r*sin(orientationImage(y,x)-pi/2);
                cx1 = x - r*cos(orientationImage(y,x)-pi/2);
                cy2 = y - r*sin(orientationImage(y,x)-pi/2);
                cx2 = x + r*cos(orientationImage(y,x)-pi/2);

                if calculated coordinates within searchwindow 
                    accumulator(cy1,cx1,r)++;
                    accumulator(cy2,cx2,r)++;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```